# Interchangeability of 'preposition + which' with relative adverbs?

Tags: difference, prepositional-phrases, relative-adverbs

> [[Source:]](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/relative-adverbs/) 
>   The relative adverbs **where, when & why** can be used to join sentences or clauses. They replace the more formal structure of **preposition + which** used to introduce a relative clause.

1. How is **preposition + which** more formal?  I did read the basics on [relative adverbs](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/adverbs.htm).

2. When are and aren't **preposition + which** interchangeable with the relative adverbs?

Comment: Compare: *My favorite month is always February, when we celebrate Valentine's Day and Presidents' Day.* vs. *My favorite month is always February, **in which** we celebrate Valentine's Day and Presidents' Day.*; *Do you know the reason why Isabel isn't in class today?* vs. *Do you know the reason **for which** Isabel isn't in class today?*; *I always look forward to the day when we begin our summer vacation.* vs. *I always look forward to the day **on which** we begin our summer vacation.*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I can justify WHY using "which" is more formal. From experience you are much less likely to hear **preposition + which** in casual conversation or informal writing, and you are more likely to hear **where, when, why**.

Switching **which** and **where, when, why** depends mostly on the style and structure of the rest of the sentence. Again, a formal or informal tone could make one a better option. I cannot think of any cases that truly cannot be changed.

**My favorite month is February, in which we celebrate President's Day.**

**My favorite month is February, when we celebrate President's Day.**

The first sentence is a little clumsy and overly formal, and you are more likely to hear the second one.

**Yesterday I visited the park where I first learned to play baseball.**

This tone is again casual and much better suited to "where" than "in which."

**The company president gave a speech in which he announced there will be layoffs.**

A layoff, losing a job, is quite serious. "In which" works quite well with the no-nonsense tone.